# Flutter List View

Tags: flutter, listview, textfield

I have a mark entry form. So I have to save different marks in each text field.  tried controllers, but its not worked. If you have any soulusion please help.

Screenshot: https://ibb.co/CbsBQMy

Comment: hello man i think u should more infos like codes & what u want to achieve & what r u getting. That will help us to understand ur prbs

Answer (score 0):

Create different controller for each marks , dispose it at end

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MarkEntryForm extends StatefulWidget {
  const MarkEntryForm({super.key});

  @override
  _MarkEntryFormState createState() => _MarkEntryFormState();
}

class _MarkEntryFormState extends State<MarkEntryForm> {
  final TextEditingController _mathsController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _scienceController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _englishController = TextEditingController();

  double _mathsMark = 0;
  double _scienceMark = 0;
  double _englishMark = 0;

  void _saveMarks() {
    _mathsMark = double.parse(_mathsController.text);
    _scienceMark = double.parse(_scienceController.text);
    _englishMark = double.parse(_englishController.text);

    // Save the marks to the database or do other processing here
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Mark Entry Form'),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            TextField(
              controller: _mathsController,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'Maths',
              ),
            ),
            TextField(
              controller: _scienceController,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'Science',
              ),
            ),
            TextField(
              controller: _englishController,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'English',
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 16),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: _saveMarks,
              child: const Text('Save Marks'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

this is a sample program that store one set of marks you can change it to LIst to store more data also we can use listview.builder to display it